# How to prove $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\leq \frac1m$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to prove the following inequality:

> $$\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}\leq \frac1m$$

But I'm stuck with it. I found online geometric justifications for this but I'd really appreciate to see actual proof. Any hints?

Comment: Thank you everybody, got it! =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \sum_{n=m+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}
&\le& \displaystyle \sum_{n=m+1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-1)n} \\
&=& \displaystyle \sum_{n=m+1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n-1} - \frac1n \right) \\
&=& \displaystyle \left(\frac{1}m - \frac1{m+1} \right) + \left(\frac{1}{m+1} - \frac1{m+2} \right) + \cdots \\
&=& \dfrac1m
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:**

For each $n$ you have
$$\frac1{n^2}\le\frac1{n(n-1)}=\frac1{n-1}-\frac1n.$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Compare with the integral $\int_{m+1}^{\infty} {1\over x^2}dx$.

Comment: You probably want the lower limit to be $1/m$ for an upper bound